# Want to make a shell script that

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, memory

Want to make a shell script that runs a program, then if the memory reach over specific limit(example 3gb), it shutdown and restart itself.

- While running
- If memory > 3gb
- Shutdown
- Restart

Comment: Which part of this are you having problems with?

Comment: Would probably get more help if you actually asked some questions. The more specific the better (and preferably with context, what you have tried and what problems you encountered).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically kill process that consume too much memory or stall on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187804/automatically-kill-process-that-consume-too-much-memory-or-stall-on-linux)

Answer (score -2):

MEM_LIMIT=3145728

MEM_USED=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep "MemFree" | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | tr -d " ")

if [ $MEM_USED -ge $MEM_LIMIT ]

then

```
    reboot 0
```

fi