# How do I automatically kill a process that uses too much memory with Python?

Tags: python, linux

**The situation:** I have a website that allows people to execute arbitrary code *in a different language* (specifically, an esolang I created), using a Python interpreter on a shared-hosting server. I run this code in a separate process which is given a time limit of 60 seconds.

**The problem:** You can do stuff like (Python equivalent) `10**(10**10)`, which rapidly consumes far more memory than I have allotted to me. It also, apparently, locks up Apache - or it takes too long to respond - so I have to restart it.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187804/automatically-kill-process-that-consume-too-much-memory-or-stall-on-linux), but the given answer uses Perl, which I do not know at all, hence I'd like an answer in Python. The OS *is* Linux too, though.

Specifically, I want the following characteristics:

1. Runs automatically
2. Force-kills any process that exceeds some memory limit like 1MB or 100MB
3. Kills any process spawned by my code that is more than 24 hours old

I use this piece of code (in a Django view) to create the process and run it (`proxy_prgm` is a Manager so I can retrieve data from the program that's interpreting the esolang code):

```
prgmT[uid] = multiprocessing.Process(
    target = proxy_prgm.runCatch,
    args = (steps,),
    name="program run")

prgmT[uid].start()
prgmT[uid].join(60) #time limit of 1 minute

if prgmT[uid].is_alive():
    prgmT[uid].terminate()
    proxy_prgm.stop()
```

If you need more details, don't hesitate to tell me what to edit in (or ask me questions).

Comment: Some ideas: You could use ulimit to set the maximum memory of the spawned process. You could use psutil to monitor memory use and kill it if it gets out of hand.

Comment: I agree you should use your operating systems' `ulimit` to watch over resources. It can be used to make sure you don't consume other resources like file locks.

Comment: Just a side note - a view doesn't seem to be the right place for such code to me.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach that might work; using [resource.setrlimit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.setrlimit) (more details [in this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308091/how-to-limit-python-heap-size)). It seems that by doing so you can set a memory limit on a process and it's subprocesses; you'll have to figure out how to handle if the limit is hit though. I don't have personal experience using it, but hopefully doing so would stop Apache from locking up on you.